# Change properties for children of SKNode in a for loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, sprite-kit, sknode

I understand that the children property of an SKNode is a read only property. Still, is there a way that in iterating over the children, it would be possible to change the properties of those children?

For example:

```
let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background.jpg")   
for child in background.children{
     child.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **children** property is readonly so you cannot add or remove elements (children) using this property (there are specific methods to do it).

However you can modify some properties of the elements inside **background.children**.

```
for child in background.children as [SKNode] {
    child.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```

Casting **background.children as [SKNode]** is secure and guaranteed by the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/children).

Answer (score 2):

You can cast the child to `SKNode` and then change the position.

```
for child in self.children {
    if let sprite = child as? SKNode {
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```